# Why does InitialOpenIssuesSensor take so long?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a SonaQube 5.1 installation which is connected to a local MySQL 5.6 database. I use it to analyse Java code that primarily uses the ADF Framework. I have many separate projects configured (of similar size and complexity) and they take an average of 2-3 minutes to analyse. However, one of the projects (USViewController) takes over 25 mins to complete. I am trying to understand why and to shorten this time.

I have tried restarting the SonarQube process (/opt/sonaqube-5.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop / start) and the MySQL service (configured as a service so just service mysql stop / start). I have also tried executing OPTIMIZE TABLE project_measures in the sonar database but all to no avail.

I can see from the output that the execution gets stuck on a step called InitialOpenIssuesSensor:

```
12:30:14.435 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=12087ms
12:30:14.435 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
12:30:14.473 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=38ms
12:30:14.473 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
12:30:14.478 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=5ms
12:30:14.478 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
12:57:08.198 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | 
time=1613720ms
12:57:08.198 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
12:57:08.220 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=22ms
12:57:08.220 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
12:57:08.279 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=59ms
```

Compare this to a run of one of the other similar projects

```
09:17:44.617 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=11011ms
09:17:44.617 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
09:17:44.741 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=124ms
09:17:44.741 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
09:17:44.750 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=9ms
09:17:44.750 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
09:17:45.604 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=854ms
09:17:45.604 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
09:17:45.613 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=9ms
09:17:45.613 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
09:17:45.654 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=41ms
```

Comment: The latest LTS version of SonarQube is 7.9.1. It will be very hard to get an answer if you don't upgrade your version and plugins. Also SonarQube no longer supports MySQL

Comment: Unfortunately, company policy prevents me from upgrading at this time. It just seems suspicious to me this project takes several hundred times  longer than all the other 'healthy' projects despite being smaller and less complex